# C++ Array Object Checking Values

Tags: c++, arrays

I am supposed to write a program with two classes, `Employee` and `Department`. When the `main()` function runs, it asks the user to choose one of the six numbered options that are displayed and creates arrays for `Employee` and `Department` objects. I'm disregarding every other option except option 1, the Create Department Option, so the focus of this issue will be the `Department` class and the `Department department[3]` array.

There is a `while` loop in the `main()` function that continuously runs until the user decides to exit. If the user enters option 1, a `Department` array object is created, and then the user also enters the `departmentID`, `departmentName`, and `departmentHeadName` for that object. The `while` loop notifies the user if the array has three `Employee` objects. However, I am having difficulties because each `departmentID` needs to be unique. For example, I cannot enter 1 for the first array object's `departmentID`, and then enter 1 again for the second array object's `departmentID`. How do I check if the user's `departmentID` input already exists in a previous object?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

// Employee Class
class Employee
{
private:
    string employeeID;
    string employeeName;
    string employeeDepartmentID;
    double employeeSalary;
    int employeeAge;

public:
    void createEmployee()
    {
        cout << "Please Enter Employee Details:" << endl;

        cout << "Employee ID : ";
        cin >> employeeID;

        cout << "Employee Name :";
        cin >> employeeName;

        cout << "Salary: $";
        cin >> employeeSalary;

        cout << "Age : ";
        cin >> employeeAge;

        cout << "Department ID : ";
        cin >> employeeDepartmentID;
    }
};

// Department Class
class Department
{
private:
    string departmentID;
    string departmentName;
    string departmentHeadName;

public:
    void createDepartment()
    {
        cout << "Please Enter Department Details: \n";

        cout << "Department ID : ";
        cin >> departmentID;

        cout << "Department Name : ";
        cin >> departmentName;

        cout << "Head of Department : ";
        cin >> departmentHeadName;
    }
};

// Function prototype
void displayMenu(); 

// Client main function
int main()
{
    Employee employee[5];
    Department department[3];

    int choice;
    int departmentCount = 0;
    int employeeCount = 0;

    while (true)
    {
        displayMenu();
        cin >> choice;

        if (choice == 1 && departmentCount < 3)
        {
            department[departmentCount].createDepartment();
            departmentCount = departmentCount + 1;
        }
        else if (choice == 1 && departmentCount >= 3)
        {
            cout << "\nThe array is full, you can not add any more Departments." << endl;
        }
        else if (choice == 2 && employeeCount < 5)
        {
            employee[employeeCount].createEmployee();
            employeeCount = employeeCount + 1;
        }
        else if (choice == 2 && employeeCount >= 5)
        {
            cout << "The array is full, you can not add any more Employees." << endl;
        }
        else if (choice == 6)
        {
            cout << "Thank you, goodbye." << endl;
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

// Display menu function
void displayMenu()
{
    cout << "1. Create Department" << endl;
    cout << "2. Create Employee" << endl;
    cout << "3. Write Out Data File" << endl;
    cout << "4. Read In Data File" << endl;
    cout << "5. Display Salary Report" << endl;
    cout << "6. -- Quit -- " << endl;
    cout << "Please make a selection : ";
}
```

Comment: `department[departmentCount].createDepartment();
if (std::any_of(department, department + departmentCount, [&](const auto& d){ return d.departmentID == department[departmentCount].departmentID; })) { std::cout << "id already present\n"; } else
            ++departmentCount;`

Comment: use a vector, this way you do not have to set a fixed limit in advance

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

// Employee Class
class Employee
{
private:
    string employeeID;
    string employeeName;
    string employeeDepartmentID;
    double employeeSalary;
    int employeeAge;

public:
    void createEmployee()
    {
        cout << "Please Enter Employee Details:" << endl;

        cout << "Employee ID : ";
        cin >> employeeID;

        cout << "Employee Name :";
        cin >> employeeName;

        cout << "Salary: $";
        cin >> employeeSalary;

        cout << "Age : ";
        cin >> employeeAge;

        cout << "Department ID : ";
        cin >> employeeDepartmentID;
    }


};

// Department Class
class Department
{
private:
    string departmentID;
    string departmentName;
    string departmentHeadName;

public:
    void createDepartment()
    {
        cout << "Please Enter Department Details: \n";

        cout << "Department ID : ";
        cin >> departmentID;

        cout << "Department Name : ";
        cin >> departmentName;

        cout << "Head of Department : ";
        cin >> departmentHeadName;
    }

      public:
        string getDepartmentID(){

            return departmentID;

          }
};


// Function prototype
void displayMenu(); 

// Client main function
int main()
{
    Employee employee[5];
    Department department[3];


    int choice;
    int departmentCount = 0;
    int employeeCount = 0;

    while (true)
    {
        displayMenu();
        cin >> choice;

        if (choice == 1 && departmentCount < 3)
        {
            department[departmentCount].createDepartment();

            for(int i=0;i<departmentCount;i++)
           {
                if(department[i].getDepartmentID()==department[departmentCount].getDepartmentID())
                 {

                    cout<<"already exists......................... \n";
                 }

            }


            departmentCount = departmentCount + 1;
        }
        else if (choice == 1 && departmentCount >= 3)
        {
            cout << "\nThe array is full, you can not add any more Departments." << endl;
        }
        else if (choice == 2 && employeeCount < 5)
        {
            employee[employeeCount].createEmployee();
            employeeCount = employeeCount + 1;
        }
        else if (choice == 2 && employeeCount >= 5)
        {
            cout << "The array is full, you can not add any more Employees." << endl;
        }
        else if (choice == 6)
        {
            cout << "Thank you, goodbye." << endl;
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

// Display menu function
void displayMenu()
{
    cout << "1. Create Department" << endl;
    cout << "2. Create Employee" << endl;
    cout << "3. Write Out Data File" << endl;
    cout << "4. Read In Data File" << endl;
    cout << "5. Display Salary Report" << endl;
    cout << "6. -- Quit -- " << endl;
    cout << "Please make a selection : ";
}
```

Comment: I recommend marking what you changed and explaining why you changed it . Otherwise you have a code only answer, and those tend to produce [Cargo Cult Programmers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming) instead of useful, thinking human beings.

Answer (score 0):

I used  getDepartmentID function in Department Class to get department id from each department object

```
public:
        string getDepartmentID(){

            return departmentID;

          }
```

there should be return type is string.because you have created departmentID as a string.

and I used For Loop in main function to compare relevant department id already exists or not

```
for(int i=0;i<departmentCount;i++)
           {
                if(department[i].getDepartmentID()==department[departmentCount].getDepartmentID())
                 {

                    cout<<"already exists......................... \n";
                 }

            }
```